# How to use ghostscript tiffcp command

Tags: ghostscript

> We installed GPL ghostscript version gs9.18.

As per documentation
http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/tiff/html/man/tiffcp.1.html
We can use tiffcp command. But when I using below command it's giving error.
Can somebody tell me how to use tiffcp using ghostscript.

```
D:\>D:\capfmw\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin64c.exe tiffcp -c none -sOutputFile="D:\testima
gefolder\ghostscript-converted-tiffs\test1.tif" D:\testimagefolder\wfr\264688.ti
ff
GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefinedfilename in (tiffcp)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   fa
lse   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1189/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not part of the Ghostscript documentation, its part of the LibTiff documentation.

Ghostscript uses LibTiff in order to create TIFF output and as part of our GPL conformance we include the entire LibTiff distribution, including the documentation.

Tiffcp is part of libtiff, not part of Ghostscript, if you want to use it you will need to build the libtiff utilities. Note that since you are using Windows you will not have the source package and so you will need to use Git to clone our repository in order to get LibTiff. Alternatively you could simply pick up libtiff from [here](http://www.libtiff.org/)